# rails activerecord multiple query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Thanks for your time !

It's a simple question but I've searched for some time and still cannot get the function suit me.

I get a table named *lr_transaction_tables* in DB and a `class LrTransactionsTable < ActiveRecord::Base` with it.

I can `@entry_ary = LrTransactionsTable.find(:all)` to fetch the whole table and present it in the view by :

```
<table id="trans-war-table">
  <% @entry_ary.each do |item| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= item.ltname %></td>
        <td><%= item.name %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

But how do I get the data `where the data under ltname column is "specific word"` instead of all of it.

I've tried `@entry_ary = LrTransactionsTable.find_by_ltname( "specific word" )`, but it give me the error that `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

`ltname` and `name` is the column name in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Rails 2

```
LrTransactionsTable.find(:all, :conditions => {:ltname => "specific word"})
```

For Rails 3

```
@entry_ary = LrTransactionsTable.where(ltname: "specific word")
```

OR

```
@entry_ary = LrTransactionsTable.where(["ltname =? ", "specific word"])
```

Comment: the `:conditions => { ... }` syntax is deprecated.

Comment: @simonmenke:- Yes, i know.He's not specify the version of the ruby he's using so gave example of both.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the `where` method to set a condition:

```
LrTransactionsTable.where(:ltname => "specific word")
```

Answer (score 1):

try best way, always right query in model

in your controller

```
LrTransactionsTable.find_ltname("specific word")
```

and write in your model

```
def find_ltname(name)
  where("ltname = ?", name)
end
```

or you can also create a scope for that

```
scope :find_ltname, lambda{|name|{ :conditions => ["ltname = ?", name]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@entry_ary = LrTransactionsTable.where(ltname: "specific word")
```